# Pass variable to Ajax / run Ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm created a google chrome extension. The problem i am having is that the Ajax function always returns undefined. If the ajax is not within in a function, then it runs successfully - however this will be the first thing that runs thus it can't read in the returned URL (from `function url`)

How can i fix this such that the Ajax function, `callAjax` can read in `mainurl` and run so that the XML document can be displayed in the text box?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click',begin);      
});
var mainURL;

function begin(){
  mainURL = url();
  callAjax();
}

function url(){
    return "https://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=9vyfTMs7Q4JVtr4u5ItN8Fd0YHuw1dqn&from=Denver%2C+CO&to=Boulder%2C+CO&outFormat=xml&ambiguities=ignore&routeType=fastest&doReverseGeocode=false&enhancedNarrative=false&avoidTimedConditions=false";
}

function callAjax(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: mainURL,
    dataType: "XML",
    success: parseXML,
     error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText); //Alerts Undefined
    }
  });
}

 //This method doesn't get called, always fails. 
function parseXML(xml) {
document.getElementById("xmlSource").textContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
document.getElementById("xmlSource").textContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml.documentElement);
  var ballList = $('distance', xml).get();
  $.each(ballList, function( index, value ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + value.textContent );
    $('#r_distance').append(value.textContent);
    return false;
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <textarea id="xmlSource" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
<form id="Formid"> 
      <input type="submit" id = "Submit" id="Submit">
 </form>https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52372845/edit#
```

Comment: Guessing you have a CORS error.... did you look at your console? Not sure why you think you would have responseText when error is called.

Comment: 0 errors in the console

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml with MIME type text/xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: @ricardofagodoy thanks. I'm unsure why it doesn't generate this error via the chrome extension but this is most likely the reason why it isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I was unaware that the sample produced a CORS error (Seeing that the URL i was using in my chrome extension did not create this)

The problem why the the ajax function kept returning `undefined` was because of the EventListener I was using start the main function.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener('click',begin);      
});
```

I don't understand why this function would cause the error but I had to change it to a Jquery on click function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Submit").click(function(event){
        begin();
        event.preventDefault(); //
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran  the snippet you provided, I got a cors error in the console.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

It's a security measure enforced server side, meant to prevent malicious calls to the server.

A simple example (provided it was possible) : you could create a dummy website that hosts a javascript snippet able to make a call to facebook, in order to perform an action only available to logged in users. If someone logged to their facebook account were to visit the website, the request could be executed sucessfully, allowing you to do whatever you're trying to do with their account.

That's why if the sever doesn't provide a header explicitly allowing this kind of call, the browser blocks the request.

TLDR : It's a security measure enforced server side, if the server doesn't accept requests from web pages that are hosted elsewhere, there is not much you can do about it !